# Search bar is not working on site

Tags: search

The search bar is not working. When we input the sku # or any details it is not able to find it.
Example, searched 17024 which is marked as an item however it does not come up.
[image]

Comment: what type of search you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried re-indexing?

Navigate to **System > Index Management** in your admin and select the relevant indexes.

Select reindex from the select box in the top left of the table, hit enter.

Before this please make sure you have set the product up correctly:
**In Stock set?**
**Qty more than 0?**
**Enabled?**

Hope this helps,

Josh

Comment: Your welcome Sam, glad i could help. For more of an explanation on the whole reindex process and why its required, please see this excellent answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945307/can-someone-explain-magentos-indexing-feature-in-detail